# How can I get the dates from a text string?

Tags: sql, string, date, extract, vertica

I use Vertical SQL and have a field "Note" that is a free text field (no consistent way to enter data). I'd like to create another field with only dates or extract the last date in the field.
E.g

1. "1st order on 3/2/21, second 5/5/21" -> "3/2/21 5/5/21" or "5/5/21"
2. "first delivery 2/2/21 second one 8/30/21" -> "2/2/21 8/30/21" or "8/30/21"
3. "reported 1st:  2/2/21." -> "2/2/21"

Thanks!

Comment: Pulling all dates from string will likely involve programming outside SQL. What is your programming interface - PHP, C#, VB.net, Access VBA? What do you mean by "Vertical SQL" - did you mean "Vertica Systems"?

Comment: I should be more clear. I am using DBeaver pulling data saved in Vertica.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to grab the patterns: one or more digits; slash; one or more digits; slash; one or more digits.

If you have more than one of those patterns, then, create one row as output for each pattern found. For that, `CROSS JOIN` with a consecutive series of integers, so you can output the n-th occurrence of the pattern. Then, cast the found string as DATE.

Finally, and only if you only need the last date, apply a Vertica-peculiar *analytic limit clause* , to only output the highest `i` value for the respective `id` (which I had to add) of the result table.

```
WITH 
-- need a sequence of integers ...
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
)
,
indata(id,s) AS (
          SELECT 1,'1st order on 3/2/21, second 5/5/21'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'first delivery 2/2/21 second one 8/30/21'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'reported 1st: 2/2/21.'
)
SELECT
  id
, i
, s
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'\d+/\d+/\d+',1,i) AS found_token
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'\d+/\d+/\d+',1,i)::DATE AS found_date
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',1,i,'',1) <>''
-- remove the following line if you want all dates from all strings
-- and keep it if you only want the last date in the string
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY i DESC)
;
 id | i |                    s                     | found_token | found_date 
----+---+------------------------------------------+-------------+------------
  1 | 2 | 1st order on 3/2/21, second 5/5/21       | 5/5/21      | 2021-05-05
  2 | 2 | first delivery 2/2/21 second one 8/30/21 | 8/30/21     | 2021-08-30
  3 | 1 | reported 1st: 2/2/21.                    | 2/2/21      | 2021-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Consistently is critical when parsing string data. If it will always end with a date preceded by a space, pulling the last date should be fairly simple. Consider:

`Trim(Mid(Note, InStrRev(Note, " ")))`